# How to represent sql joins in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, database, ansi-sql

I am looking for a way to represent SQL joins in JSON format.

**One way that I could think of is :**

```
{
    type: 'select',
    table: 'table1',
    innerjoin: {
        table2: {
            on: [userid', 'userId'] //table1Key,table2Key
        }
    }
}
```

**But the problem is what if there are joins between N no. of tables? And what if the join is based on more than a single column?**

**Eg:**

```
SELECT x1,x2...., FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.id=t3.Id  
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 on t3.Id=t4.Id and t3.name=t4.name
```

Comment: This is much more complicated that you may think. The SQL syntax is rich and expressive. You might want to use an ORM rather than try and reinvent that wheel.

Comment: This will end up being very complex, since there are many options available when querying and joining.

Comment: And [so] is not the place for general design discussions.

Comment: @GMB I am well aware that this could be complex. But let's say that we eliminate other use cases such as using any operator other than `= ` or any Built-In function. I am able to represent joins between two tables. I just want to extend it to say 4 tables max. Do you think it could be done?

Comment: This would be more appropriate for a forum where you could have a brainstorming session to come up with a design.

Comment: @Barmar please recommend one?

Answer (score 1):

I would take an array approach like below :

```
{
    type: 'select',
    table: 'table1',
    joins: [{
        type : 'inner'
        from :'table1'
        to :'table2'
        on : { 'userId':'userId' // property belongs to from value belongs to to table
            'secondColumn':'secondOne'
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: @Barmar yes but in more complex queries it won't be always the outer object.